# Distribution of composite numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory, twin-primes

This question is moved from mathoverflow, there are several excellent answers at mathoverflow which improve my question greatly. For more information, please see the original question posted on mathoverflow,  the link is :https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204733/distribution-of-composite-numbers

Motivation: I want to give an abstract formulation of Eratosthenes's Sieve and try to conject a property of Eratosthenes's Sieve.  If this property are right, then I can use it to find a low bound of numbers of primes between any segment $[1,N]$ in the set of natural numbers,  so this problem is connected to distribution of primes.

The following statement can be seen as  **conjectured properties**  of distribution of composite numbers.

*** ** version 5 **: 
Let $N$ be a natural numbers.   $d_i$ $(1\leq i\leq n)$ and $x$ are distinct prime numbers less than or equal to $\sqrt{N}$.  $A_i=\{multiples\  of\  d_i\}\cap [1,N]$ $(1\leq i\leq n)$.
If $x>3$, then the density of multiples of $x$ in $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$ is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{x-2}$.***

Comment: Whoa... That's a lot to read.  Is there any way to ask a shorter question?

Comment: No pain no gain.

Comment: And by the looks of it anyone who reads this is going to gain a lot.

Comment: @abiessu: now the question becomes short,

Comment: @Gamamal: I won't disagree about possibly learning quite a bit, but I think the question deserves more attention than its (former) length will (would have) inspire(d).

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Take $d_1=5$ say, and take $d_2,\dots,d_n$ to be primes near $\sqrt N$. Then $A_1$ has size about $N/5$, while $A_2\cup\dots\cup A_n$ has size about $(n-1)\sqrt N$. Now take $x=d_1$: the multiples of $x$ in $A_1\cup\dots\cup A_n$ is virtually all of it - it has density $1 > \frac1{5-2}$.

Comment: Thanks,   but your answer does not fit for my question.  "the multiples of x in A1∪⋯∪An is virtually all of it - it has density 1>15−2."  In my question, I ask the density of multiples of $x$ in $A_2\cup\cdots \cup A_n$, not in $A_1\cup A_2\cup\cdots\cup A_n$

Comment: If the answer doesn't fit the question, then why have you accepted the answer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have answered the question you wrote, even if that's not the question you intended to write.